# Are "Birth of Levi" and "A Choice with No Regrets" the same OVA?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I can't find whether *Birth of Levi* and *A Choice with No Regrets* are actually two different OVA or the same. Are they different?

Edit: I found out they are the same.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Surely this is trivially answered by just watching them?